# Trying to use hibernate bean outside controller (in a class) and running into invoking related issue

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I'm trying to use `CompanyManager` interface inside an `Order` class as follows:

```
public class Order extends OrderBase implements CompanySummary, CompanyItem, Serializable {
private CompanyManager compLocMgr;
    
    public void setCompanyManager(CompanyManager companyLocationManager) {
        this.compLocMgr = companyLocationManager;
    }  
    
    public String getCompanyDisplay() {

        String result = "";
        if (companyHandler != null) {
            result = companyHandler.getAttribute(CompanyHandler.COMPANY_LOCATION);
            SampleLocation captureList = compLocMgr.getCompany(Integer.parseInt(result));
            System.out.println(captureList);
        }
        return result;
    } 

}
```

And I keep getting following error:

```
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] ERROR - CompanyAdminController.renderErrorPage(88) | 500 Internal Server Error - COMPANY ADMIN - URL: /companyadmin/casesearch.html Error: Cannot invoke "com.pending.service.CompanyManager.getCompany(java.lang.Integer)" because "this.compLocMgr" is null
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] [2023-08-01 13:34:37,410] ERROR com.pending.web.controller.CompanyAdminController 500 Internal Server Error - COMPANY ADMIN - URL: /companyadmin/casesearch.html Error: Cannot invoke "com.pending.service.CompanyManager.getCompany(java.lang.Integer)" because "this.compLocMgr" is null
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] [2023-08-01 13:34:37,410] ERROR com.pending.web.controller.CompanyAdminController 500 Internal Server Error - COMPANY ADMIN - URL: /companyadmin/casesearch.html Error: Cannot invoke "com.pending.service.CompanyManager.getCompany(java.lang.Integer)" because "this.compLocMgr" is null
```

I have a bean defined in `applicationContext.xml` as folows:

```
<bean id="companyManager" parent="txProxyTemplateMYDB">
    <property name="target">
    <bean class="com.pending.service.impl.CompanyManagerImpl">
       <property name="companyDAO">
          <ref bean="companyDAO" />
        </property>
    </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Whenever I've had to use the same thing in a Spring Controller class, I have always got it working by definining the following inside `companyadmin-servlet.xml` and defining the setter in the same manner as I did in `Order` class above.

For example:

```
<bean id="companyCreateNewLocationController"
class="com.pending.web.controller.CompanyCreateNewLocationController">
    <property name="companyManager">
        <ref bean="companyManager" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

But this is the first time I'm trying to use it in a class without any controller (in the Order class) above and running into this problem. Any idea what I'm missing?

Here's my `Company` class inside `com.pending.model`:

```
public class Company{
     
         
        private Integer id;
        private String name;
        private String comment;
        public Integer getId() {
            return id;
        }
        public void setId(Integer id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public String getComment() {
            return comment;
        }
        public void setComment(String comment) {
            this.comment = comment;
        }
 
         
}
```

`CompanyManager` interface inside `com.pending.service` is as follows:

```
public interface CompanyManager {
    public void setCompanyDAO(CompanyDAO dao);
    public Company getCompany(Integer id);  
    public void saveCompany(Company company);
 
}
```

`CompanyManagerImpl` in `com.pending.service.impl`

```
public class CompanyManagerImpl implements CompanyManager {
    private CompanyDAO dao;
 
    public void setCompanyDAO(CompanyDAO dao) {
        this.dao = dao;
 
    }
 
    public void saveCompany(Company company) {
        dao.saveCompany(company);
 
    }
 
    public Company getCompany(Integer id) {
 
        return dao.getCompany(id);
    }
 
}
```

`CompanyDAO` inside `com.pending.dao`

```
public interface CompanyDAO {
 
    public Company getCompany(Integer id);
    public Company saveCompany(Company company);
 
}
```

`CompanyDaoHibernate` in `com.pending.dao.hibernate`

```
public class CompanyDAOHibernate extends HibernateDaoSupport implements CompanyDAO {
 
    @Override
    public Company saveCompany(Company company) {
        getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdate(company);
 
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("Company id is: " + company.getId());
        }
        return company;
    }
 
    @Override
    public Company getCompany(Integer id) {
        Company company = (Company) getHibernateTemplate().get(Company.class, id);
        if (company == null) {
            throw new ObjectRetrievalFailureException(Company.class, id);
        }
        return company;
    }
```

And my `Company.hbm.xml` looks ike following:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
   "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
   "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
   <hibernate-mapping>
   <class name="com.pending.model.Company" table="company">
   <id name="id" column="id" unsaved-value="null">
   <generator class="native" />
   </id>
   <property name="name" />
   <property name="comment" />
   </class>
   </hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: where is Order instance initialized？ Please make sure it is managed by spring container.

Comment: Trying to figure it out. But other methods used in this class are using struts.Is it possible or is there a possibility to use ApplicationContext to get the bean in Order class to fix my above issue?

Comment: Can i figure out using eclipse debugger where this Order class is initialized?It's a very large code base and I can put a breakpoint int the method and figure out?

Comment: Maybe you could add one default constructor for Order class and put one breakpoint there, then check information such as the calling stack or classLoader to find some clue. I am wondering if order instance is really initialized.

Comment: How about if I define a separate bean for Order class in applicationContex.xml like this: `<bean id="companyManager" parent="txProxyTemplateMYDB">
    <property name="target">
    <bean class="com.pending.service.Order">
       <property name="companyDAO">
          <ref bean="companyDAO" />
        </property>
    </bean>
    </property>
</bean>`

Comment: Is it okay to have bean with same `id`, `companyManager` inside `applicationContext.xml`? I already have one with same id as shown in my post.